# EPPlus row insertion with merged cells

Tags: merge, insert, epplus

I want to insert row in an loaded Excel table where there are vertically merged cells and as you see it is not perfect:

[image]

EPPlus code:

```
sheet.InsertRow(3, 1);
```

How can I insert one or more rows in a existing Excel table which contains merged cells, please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
sheet.InsertRow(3, 1, 2);
Parameter 3 specifies the line number whose style is to be applied to the new line.